# Saving Prefab with AR/VR Toolkit doesn't work

Tags: autodesk-forge

I used Autodesk Forge AR/VR Toolkit unity plugin to load a model statically, and then save it as a prefab, then I tried to load the prefab in another project. It just doesn't show up. It doesn't show up even in the same project(if u delete the loaded model and load from the prefab you saved). I am wondering why?

I noticed that the model loaded from Forge AR/VR toolkit doesn't have mesh component and I guess that's the reason. But how come it can be shown correctly when loaded from Forge? How to solve this problem?

Below are some screen-shots

[The model is successfully loaded statically from Forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oIq2.png)
[The prefab was created successfully but when dragging it into project it is invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp6Z5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you probably created a prefab from the game engine versus the editor. You need to understands how Unity is working regarding creating assets on disk. To create a static prefab, do not launch the game engine, but use the Forge menu, make sure to check the 'Save To Disk' option. After importing the asset, you will see a pivot object in the hierarchy, and a folder in the Resources folder of the Project. Select the pivot object in the hierarchy tree, and select the Forge Menu again, and 'Create Prefab' - that should work just fine now.

Comment: Hi, Cyrille
Thanks for your anwser. I did exactly what you said. 

Please refer to the screenshot above, I didn't launch the game engine, instead I used "Import Scene" in Forge menu and loaded it statically, when it's completed I got a scenePivotä object it's shown correctly in Unity editor. Then I use 'Build Prefab' function in Forge menu to build the prefab, then the prefab can be found in 'Resources' folder. However, then if I drag the prefab back into the project or other project, it is invisible!

Comment: can you contact me on my email address, we do screen sharing to know what's going wrong - my email address is my firstname @ autodesk.com

Comment: I just dropped u a mail with some screen-shot. Thank you.

Comment: problem solved, the problem was that lin was not copying all files across projects.